# git rebase origin/master vs git reset origin/master if you have no local commits

Tags: git, rebase, git-reset

If you have no local commits or changes on your branch, is there any difference between doing a `git rebase origin/master` vs `git reset origin/master` after doing `git fetch`?

It seems the two equivalent when I try it empirically.

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted so fast, but aside from the difference in your working tree, it's true that in the *common case* that you've mentioned, the effect on recorded commit hash is the same. But it's not a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario, since you have no local commits or changes on your branch either of the commands will result in the same.

However, `git rebase` and `git reset` work very differently. The `git rebase` rewrites the commit history. `git reset`, on the other hand, works with references, it simply ignores any changes on your local branch and makes it exactly the same as `origin/master`.